# Problems running java from command line in windows

Tags: java, windows-7, command-line

I'm trying to compile and run java file using the command line, but it's not working. I've followed the steps on http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/windows-cmd.html, using the correct file path and a current jdk and I still get `javac is not recognized` when typing `javac -version`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please paste the full jdk\bin present in your `PATH`

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;                              `javac` works now, but when trying to run my simple java file by entering `java test` I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the folder where `javac` exists to your PATH. It might not be the same path specified in the given link.

Comment: close cmd and start again, the path is not refreshed for an already opened session

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) to set `PATH` and `CLASSPATH` for java in windows